# Dimension and Rank of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been watching Linear Algebra series of 3B1B where he says that "Rank= Number of Dimensions in the output".

Now consider this scenario. Say I have this matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}

And a vector say,

\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
6
\end{bmatrix}

Now clearly the rank of the matrix is 1 as its determinant is 0. Now say I apply this transformation on this vector,

The output is

\begin{bmatrix}
10\\
10
\end{bmatrix}

Isn't it still 2-Dimensional? Shouldn't the vector be squished to 1D only since the rank of the matrix is one? Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Dimensions of the output" refers to the dimension of the set $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} : \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2\right\}$ rather than the number of entries in a vector. As
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1+v_2 \\ v_1 + v_2 \end{pmatrix},$$
this translates to all vectors $\begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy $w_1 = w_2$. This describes a straight line, which is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Given *any* vector $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, $A.\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x+y\\x+y\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Therefore the range of $A$ is $\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\x\end{smallmatrix}\right]\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}$, and$$\dim\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\x\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}=1.$$Besides: vector spaces have dimensions; vectors don't.